# PHP adding only a new record to a SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to only new data to a database table. I am trying to query the database but and only add new data. I am somewhat lost in SQL and PHP.

I have got the code entering to the database but on refresh it will enter the same data again and I only want it to allow new data:

```
<?php

// DATA BASE CONNECTION 

DEFINE ('DB_USERS', 'root');
DEFINE ('DB_PASS', 'root');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'sam_api');

$dbc = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USERS, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) OR die ('could not connect' . mysqli_connect_error());


$user_update = $items['id'];



// Check if file already exists

 $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM updates WHERE $user_update ='".$items['id']."'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){

    echo "email already exists";
}else{
    // do something
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$query))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
}


// now inserting the data form the previous page in to the database 
$q = "INSERT INTO updates (user_update) VALUES ('$user_update')";
$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc,$q);



// telling you if it has been uploaded or not 
if($r){
    echo "you have successfully inserted";
} else{
    echo "this did not work";
}


?>
```

Comment: `$user_update ='".$items['id']."'"` this doesn't make sense, if this value is equal to `1`, then its `1='1'`. are you sure about this one

Comment: please improve the question to explain more about the rules of when data should insert or not. this can be approached either from an client-state perspective or from a data uniqueness perspective. your explanation will help. avoid post on refresh or avoid inserting duplicate data?

Answer (score 0):

Remove $ from user_update, because you want to compare field's value, not value with itself.

```
 $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM updates WHERE user_update ='".$items['id']."'");
```